# I cant delete the first row that was added to the cart laravel 5.8 bumbummen99 library

Tags: e-commerce, laravel-5.8

I cant delete the first row from the item added to cart. I used Laravel 5.8 with `bumbummen99/shoppingcart`. Other rows can be deleted successfully but 
I can't delete the first row. Please I need help

```
<form action="{{ url('cart', [$item->rowId]) }}" method="POST">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">                
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</button></td>

 </form>
```

Above is my view

Below is my route

```
Route::delete('/cart/{product}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

Below is my controller with the destroy method

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        Cart::remove($id);            

        return back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed');
    }
```

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Comment: Can you update your question with your other routes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be solved by changing your `method` attribute on your `<form>` to from `POST` to `DELETE`:

```
<form action="{{ url('cart', [$item->rowId]) }}" method="DELETE">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">                
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</button></td>
</form>
```

Comment: It didnt work. im working on a project and i cant move past this. need help

Comment: @jesse-emeka please update your question with all you're routes

Comment: Also, does removing the hidden input help?